# Old and New Versions of Android Studio for Vista

Tags: android-studio, windows-vista

Android Studio 2.1 seems to only support Windows 7 onwards, is it possible to install it on the Vista devices and run it? Is there any official link from Android which has the old versions of the Android Studio?

Comment: try this link 
http://www.android-examples.com/how-to-install-android-studio-on-windows-xp7810/

Comment: here is old version 
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Android-Studio.shtml

Comment: FYI: I was able to install and run Studio 2.2 on Windows Vista with no difficulty. (I did not test emulation, but debugging on phones works just fine.)